# How to use vim as editor in Matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, vim, editor

I am using Matlab R2013b. I am using the GUI, with the Command Windows and Editor in split screen. In the Matlab preferences > Editor/Debugger > Editor. There is an option to set a custom editor instead of the Matlab editor. I set it to my local editor `/usr/bin/vim`, but then I am not able to open files at all anymore. Is there a possibility to use the `vim` editor in split screen mode?

I am aware of `!vim file.m`, but this is not the solution I am looking for, as this only works satisfactory in `-nodisplay` mode. I rather want to keep the split screen mode.

Comment: Have you tried setting `/usr/bin/gvim` instead?

Comment: …or if you prefer the console version (vim), wrap the call in another one that starts a terminal emulator.

Comment: @merlin2011 Yes, but it is not present on my system where I am not root.

Comment: @A.Donda Did not try that, but will I be able to achieve the split screen that I am pursuing?

Comment: @Bernhard, You can build `gvim` yourself on a machine that you are not root on, and just specify the path to your version.

Comment: I never tried an external editor, but I guess you just get two windows, which you can put side-by-side manually.

Comment: @A.Donda If it is not embedded, this route would not add anything for me. I would really like an embedded editor, but I have the strong impression that it is not possible.

Comment: I don't think it can be embedded. As far as I understand, embedding needs some common interface between the caller and the called program, which is not present in an arbitrary editor binary.

Answer (score 13):

I did not find a solution that is 100% satisfying, but for now I am using [`tmux`](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) as an intermediate solution. It allows two use a split screen for two terminals. In one of those I can open `matlab -nodesktop` in terminal mode, and in the other one `vim`. It is possible to quickly switch between both split screens.

You can use functionality of GUI Matlab by typing things as `commandhistory`, `who` et cetera.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using something such as `screen` or `tmux`, you can use vim's `:term` command (needs to be compiled with the `+terminal` feature). This way you can open your file on a window and run `:term matlab -nodesktop` to open another window with the Matlab shell (if you want a vertical window, run `:vert term matlab -nodesktop`).

Also, you might want to have a look at [vim-slime](https://github.com/jpalardy/vim-slime).